# Do clumsy and flat-footed penalties to AC stack?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

Let's assume I am playing my character in Pathfinder 2 and am attempting to stab my foe.
This foe is clumsy 3 (because of a spell my friend casted earlier) and I somehow also have it flat-footed.

As far as I know being clumsy gives a status penalty to AC, as does being flat-footed, and those two penalties of the same type don't stack (so the total penalty would be -3). However pretty much anyone I played with seems to consider they stack (and thus in the former example the foe should have a total penalty of -5). Are they correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Clumsy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=3) causes a status penalty. [Flat-footed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=16) causes a circumstance penalty. These are different types of penalty, so both apply, [as per the rules on modifiers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=315).